# How to post id with auto increment and without duplication

Tags: php, mysql

How can i post integer id in database manually without a duplication.I tried many codes but not working.

Below is my code how can i check if id is empty and Post id without duplicating

```
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>
        <?php
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $i=1;
        if($row['id']!=$id){
        $i=1;
        }
        $id = $row['id'];
        $query="INSERT INTO table (id,name,) VALUES('$id','$name')";
        i++;
        ?>
```

Comment: in mysql make id column as Primary and auto-increment

Comment: Creating autoincrements that way is risky. Use mysqls built in possibilites, e.g. auto increment fields.

Comment: but how can we do it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to set id in insert query you can do that

```
$query="INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES('$name')";
```

and set id column as Primary and auto-increment in database

Comment: its possible with get last inserted id and plus 1 and insert in database

Answer (score 0):

Always use table creation like that

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
ID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

run this sql query on phpmyadmin or mysql terminal . it will create the table with two column name ID and Name and column ID with primary key and auto increment.  whenevery you insert the new record  you don't need to check duplicate value new record will store with NEW ID .

Comment: I know all that creating table auto increment in database but i want to know manually  my requirements is manually insert id using php if id is empty add id 1 and if id already 1 increment new id to 2 how can i do that...

Comment: you have to store last insert id via $last_id= mysql_insert_id() and next insertion just add increment ($last_id=$last_id+1) and execute insert. you can store $last_id in array or session .